# How to process file content in bash

Tags: bash, sed, file-processing

I want to process PHP files on the content but i'm only interested in the parts between **< ?php ... ?>**. The rest should be removed and saved to a new file. Below I've already part of the code based on the code from this page [multi line sed search](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/). But it only gives the first part in .

```
start="<?php"
end="?>"
temp=$(sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/.*'"$start"'//pI;d;}' <<< echo $filename)
output=$(sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/'"$end"'.*//p;d;}' <<< "$temp")
```

Somebody has a solution? awk, grep is also oké. THanks

Comment: can you add some example input? better with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this one-liner may work for you:

```
 awk '/<?php/{f=1} /?>/&&f{print;f=0} f'  file
```

if you don't want the `<?php` and `?>` in output:

```
 awk '/<?php/{f=1;next;} /?>/&&f{f=0} f' file
```

test: (I hope the output is what you are looking for. to save to new file, you could redirect output to a new file)

```
kent$  cat test.txt 
<?php
all
text

here
should
be
saved

even if 

empty

lines

?>


foo

bar

should be removed

kent$  awk '/<?php/{f=1} /?>/&&f{print;f=0} f' test.txt                                                                                                                     
<?php
all
text

here
should
be
saved

even if 

empty

lines

?>
```

Comment: You don't need an explicit print or next, just put the conditions in the right order : `awk '/<?php/{f=1} f; f&&/?>/{f=0}'` and `awk 'f&&/?>/{f=0} f; /<?php/{f=1}'` respectively.